# Chai exports are not found in Mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, node-modules, chai

I have created simple Mocha test. It works perfectly when Node "assert" module is used. I run it from command line (Mocha is installed as a global node module):

```
$ mocha myTest.js

․

1 test complete (6 ms)
```

The script looks like this:

```
var assert = require("assert")
describe('Array', function(){
    describe('#indexOf()', function(){
        it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function(){
            assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(5));
            assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(0));
        })
    })
})
```

Well, I tried to add Chai instead of assert library. I installed it first:

```
npm install chai
```

So, the directory node_modules has been created in my project. Great so far. Then, I altered the script to use Chai:

```
var chai = require("chai");

describe('Array', function(){
    describe('#indexOf()', function(){
        it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function(){
            [1,2,3].indexOf(5).should.equal(-1);
            expect([1,2,3].indexOf(5)).to.equal(-1);
            assert.equal([1,2,3].indexOf(5),-1);
        })
    })
});
```

It does not work, Mocha test fails with TypeError:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'equal' of undefined
```

I assume Chai did not define should so it is undefined.

How is this possible?

How can I make my tests run with Chai? I have tried to install Chai globally with no effect. I also ran the script with `-r chai` with no effect as well.

Apparently, Chai module is loaded, but does not define the variables (Object.prototype properties). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
```

That will get your `expect` calls working. However, you also have a `should` call which comes from a different library entirely, so change

```
[1,2,3].indexOf(5).should.equal(-1);
```

to

```
expect([1,2,3].indexOf(5)).to.equal(-1);
```

Comment: Yes. This is the design decision the CommonJS community has made. Explicitly declared dependencies, even if verbose, are preferable to implicit dependencies.

Comment: In my case, I just get a message saying that 'require' is undefined. I am running mocha via karma in gulp

Comment: This question is about node.js. If you are running in a browser, you'll need a module bundler such as browserify or webpack if you want to use commonjs `require`. Otherwise, just follow the chai directions for loading it into the browser global namespace and use it directly without require.